# Loading a Form with Repeated Items: All Items are Numbered as "1"

Tags: cognito-forms

REF: [Update permitting large data sets to be prepopulated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78534/calling-cognito-load-results-in-a-url-that-is-too-long/78713#78713).

That (awesome) ability to prepopulate large datasets into forms has exposed a presentation issue. When we initially enter data for repeating items, say identifying each child, each repeated section is numbered sequentially in the browser, e.g. Child 1, Child 2, etc. HOWEVER, when the same data are sent back to the form to prepopulate it, each child is presented as Child 1. So if there are 3 children, we get Child 1, Child 1, Child 1. The data are fine, the numbering is just a little startling.

QUESTION: Do we need to provide an ordinal number for each Child object? Or might this be resolved in a future update?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have identified this as a bug and were already actively working on it.  It should be resolved by a hotfix next week.  As you stated, the entry is just fine and will look correct when managing entries  This is a presentation issue that will be corrected on our end.